# Converting date field to return only Day field

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am working for a POS company, i have a query in my program that gets date from multiple tables and one of the fields it returns is a date field that returns the the date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. Is there a way to get my query to bring this date field in the form 'dd'? if yes how?

Comment: And how this relates to `[delphi]`?

Comment: it is an actual date field here is my query 'select sum(cashsalesamount + creditsalesamount - creditreturnsamount) as amount, salesdate
from salesreportstable
group by salesdate'

Comment: I am programming the system within delphi

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Delphi. (The fact you're programming the system using it is meaningless, as your question is not about programming.) Your question is strictly about MySQL and SQL. I've removed the 'delphi' tag. Please only use tags that are actually relevant to your question, so that the filtering and search functionality works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `date_format()` function (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)):

```
select date_format(<datefield>, '%d');
```

This returns the value as a string.  If you want it as a number, just use `day()`:

```
select day(<datefield>)
```

Comment: THANKS, I have a very complex query, should i just add this next to the part that gets the date?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this:-

```
EXTRACT(unit FROM date)
```

or try this:-

```
SELECT DAY(your_date_field) AS dtDay FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

select DATE_FORMAT(your_date_column,' %d ') FROM your_table

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Delphi, why not a Delphi solution:

- open the query in a dataset
- get the corresponding field
- get the value with AsDateTime
- use function DayOf from System.DateUtils to retreive the day
- in case you need a dataset field for that, create a calulated field
- move the day calculation into the OnCalcFields event of the dataset

There might still be plenty of other ways to do it.